# By what mechanism does LinkedIn tell so fast, on group page, the connections of user who are also a part of that group?

Tags: database, database-design, linkedin-api

By what mechanism does LinkedIn tell so fast, on group page, the connections of user who are also a part of that group?

Comment: With a database query, presumably.  No-one here is privy to the LinkedIn database structure, so all you will get is guesses...

Comment: yes that's what is expected & suggestions on, as to how that can be implemented :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any inside knowledge of Linkedin source code but I do know that they are the founding contributors of the nosql distributed key-value database Project Voldermort http://project-voldemort.com/. These kinds of systems are architected to return queries blazingly fast. They are often ideal for write seldom/read often scenarios and tend to sacrifice consistency for high scalability and availability.